# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer doesn't work in a custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

### Problem

I am unable to use a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to recognize edge swipes from the right or left edge of the screen in a custom keyboard extension. I created a new project to test this. Other `UIGestureRecognizer`'s work fine as explained below.

### Example

```
@implementation KeyboardViewController // A subclass of UIInputViewController
...
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  ...
  UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture)];
  [gestureRecognizer setEdges:UIRectEdgeAll];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleGesture
{
  NSLog(@"gesture handled");
}
```

#### [Download my example project on Github](https://github.com/dmzza/ExampleKeyboard/tree/gestureRecognizers)

### Possible workaround

If I change it to a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or a `UITapGestureRecognizer` I see `gesture handled` in the console. I could use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that only accepts gestures that start near the edge of the screen.

[Kiwi Keyboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kiwi-beautiful-colorful-custom/id889343355?mt=8) uses a workaround like this.

**Caveat:** The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` only works if `self.view` has a background color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, despite the name edges, `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`'s `edges` must be set to a single edge. `UIRectEdgeAll` will not work, you have to create a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` for each edge, you can't OR edges together.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I ever tried that, but it worked now. For anybody interested, I have updated my example project with edge swipes working from the right and left. https://github.com/dmzza/ExampleKeyboard/commit/de4e50152e489f99234cb9bcd5fec3573e090bfd

Comment: OMG thank you very much, you saved me a day!